# Xpages, picklist

Tags: xpages, picklist

Just curious for creating a picklist is this still the best option http://www.notesin9.com/2011/05/24/notesin9-027-the-view-picker-custom-control or is there something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, that picker pre-dated Extension Library, which provided a Value Picker and Name Picker

Comment: I realize now I am not giving enough information in my question.  I have a contact record, I want to associate that contact record with a specific company record by picking from a list of companies.  After selecting the company it should update the company name, address, phone, etc.  I assume I would do this by showing a view of company names, then setting a doc id in background and updating associated fields on the contact record.  So value picker doesn't really work for that.  I assume this is a common task and I just trying to use the wrong tools to achieve my result.

Comment: Erik - My Episode 18 of NotesIn9 did an example of something like this.  Relating documents together and stuff.  Again, it's pretty old and I wasn't doing Java back then, but I would think the information still works.  http://www.notesin9.com/2010/05/12/notes-in-9-018-xpages-data-relationships/

Comment: No, it's not an uncommon task. Remember the Value Picker is updating a component on the page (Edit Box, though my preference is Dojo List Text Box - better user experience). That component has event handlers, one of which is a onChange event. Knowing that information, there are two options:
1) Value Picker returns UNID to a hidden input, which has the event handler to set the visible information.
2) Value Picker returns the company name to the Dojo List Text Box, which gets the UNID again and sets everything.
Just remember the event handler wants to skip validation.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to answer a "best option" question here.  That control was very good - but it's fairly old right now and the developer has moved on.  So it might work but I'm not sure I'd call anything that's not actively maintained the best option.

Rather then trying to make a generic all around custom control I personally think the best option is to build the picker that you need.

Comment: Ok, can you point me in the direction of an example picker for just showing a list and pulling a doc id? I have a feeling I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Erik - Here's an example of a "picker" you can use.  I did this a long time ago but the concepts are still very valid I think.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPSAjgqvVK4

Comment: Thanks David.  I think I am headed down the right path.  I just had a disconnect on the picker and the back end action after.